# ASP.NET MVC Routing: How do I redirect all actions to Base Url?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Is there anyway to make all actions in a given controller to redirect to the server root?

For example, if I have a URL with controller **Home** and action **terms** I want that to the URL to become /terms

If I have another URL with controller **Home** and action **privacy**, then the URL should become /privacy.

I am able to do this by hard-coding 2 routes, but is there a way to automatically do this?

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Term",
    "terms",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "terms" }
 );

routes.MapRoute(
    "Privacy",
    "privacy",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "privacy" }
);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "ActionOnly",
    "{action}",
    new { controller = "Home" }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard coding the two routes is the automatic way.

Comment: I don't see anything automatic in hardcoding :-)

Comment: True, but it is easier than having to write an http handler or module.

Comment: Who said that you have to write an http handler or module?

Comment: @Darin : clearly not you since you know how to write it as one line of code -- from my perspective just being able to use MapRoute is easier than the ways I've had to do it for years.  Yes I was being flip :)